# Inno Setup: Make desktop icon 'Run as administrator'

Tags: icons, inno-setup

Using Inno Setup I need to create a desktop icon that will run the associated exe as administrator. I can create the icon but I can't find the method to set in the icon 'run as administrator'.

The administrator priviledge is required because the exe is installed in the Windows 7 'program' folder and uses .ini files to write working parameters. Since I am not the creator of the program I have no option to change anything about the way the programm works. The creator of the program is unreachable.

The user that runs the Inno Setup installer is an administrator.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @RobeN. I have seen your solution before but I did not realise it solves my problem. It is not the icon that needs a seting but the associated exe. Your solution has solved my problem. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @RobeN: I love to but my reputation is not yet sufficient. I have to dream up some more questions ;-).